# How to customize cognito user pool authorizer's Unauthorized 401 JSON response in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I have added **Cognito User pool as a Authorizer** in AWS API Gateway.
Then I have tested this authorizer with id_token and it is working fine.
I have used lambda functions for user registration/login with Cognito user pool.

Now my question is how to customize the error response when id_token is expired or when cognito authorizer fails to authenticate current user. Currently I am only getting

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

**OR**

```
{
    "message": "The incoming token has expired"
}
```

with ***401* response**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [Gateway Responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html) in API Gateway to modify the HTTP status code and response that goes back to a client.

By default, for the scenario you have described, the response is "Unauthorized" and status code is 401. To change this -

1. Go to "Gateway Responses" on the left column for your API.
2. Select "Unauthorized" and click on "Edit" on top right.
3. Click on "application/json: under "Response templates".
4. Modify the message there as `{"message":"Your custom message"}` in the "Response body template" section (see screenshot below).
5. Deploy the API and wait for a minute for changes to propagate.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new at AWS, this helps me a lot.